# Time-out connecting Xdebug in VSCode

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to debug some Laravel code in VSCode:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

I have tried different ports but no change !

php.ini configuration :

```
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9000
```

launch.json configuration :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug on Homestead",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/home/vagrant/Code/tighten-app-homestead": "/Users/jose/Code/tighten-app-homestead"
            },
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, I'm on Windows, not Linux!

Comment: It's not an error, only a notice. Obviously your IDE isn't listening to... change "start_with_request" to "no", or start listening to the debug request...

Answer (score -1):

I was also searching for solutions after I fixed the debugging setting in WordPress using the answers by creator Derick.

Then I tested for Laravel and was facing the exact error you were facing. Then, looking closely at the setting, realized that we need to use `port: 9003` instead of `9000`

Check Out: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#Step-Debugging

Solution:

Change the port

`"port": 9000`

To

`"port": 9003`

Also, you can read my questions and answers at [Xdebug shows method doesn't exist message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66810512/xdebug-shows-method-doesnt-exist-message)