# Xdebug shows method doesn't exist message

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to implement Xdebug in my VSCode for WordPress project. I am using XAMPP and PHP 7.4.15. I have set up Xdebug on my computer (Windows 10).

#### launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

#### php.ini

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_host = localhost
zend_extension="G:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.3-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
```

I have installed `PHP Debug` Extension by Felix Becker on my VSCode. Restarted my XAMPP and VSCode several times.

I have made several breakpoints on `index.php` file of my theme (Currently active).

[image]

I set the setting `Listen for xDebug (wptest)`. But, When I run the debug, and refresh my index.php page, it shows me following error:

[image]

Any lead on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xdebug is initiating a break-point here, likely because it was instructed to do so by VSCode. You can verify this by checking the `breakpoint_set` lines inside the Xdebug log file, which you can create by setting `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` in php.ini.

On the bottom left of your last screenshot, you can see that there is a tick set for "Everything". For the VS Code plugin that means setting an Xdebug break-point on `*`, which includes every exception, including ones that are caught. If you un tick the box, Xdebug should no longer generate a break-point to interrupt your code here.

Comment: Thank you for your response and thank you for this amazing tool. The problem seems solved for WordPress. However For Laravel Project, when I did the same for Laravel Project (Listen for XDebug LaravelProject), it didn't stop at the breakpoints.

Comment: When I checked at the terminal, it's showing ` [Fri Mar 26 16:28:26 2021] Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

Comment: The Laravel issue is unrelated, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699093/time-out-connecting-xdebug-in-vscode might point to possible solutions in the future.